# Uninstalled retropi now not usable. brand new user

Tags: raspbian

[image]brand new user here. Actually my son, but trying to help him. We got a used pi 3 B off Ebay. it came installed with retro pi. My son didn't want that so from the dropdown menu he clicked uninstall. Now all we see is a very long boot up string but never comes to a home screen.  I'm thinking he uninstalled or deleted more than he should have. Do we have to start from scratch and make a new sd card? 
Would it be easier just to buy a new sd card with the latest os on it?

Comment: Writing an image to the SD card is easy if you have PC and an SD card writer.  See https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/.  Could you provide a legible photo of the boot up string?

Comment: the boot screen scrolls so i wouldn't be able to capture the whole string. So did he really "wipe out" the sd card?

Comment: I doubt it.  Could you describe or provide a photo of the screen once it is settled?

Comment: done. i'm currently downloading both NOOB and rasbian stretch

Comment: It seems to have booted okay and auto logged in as user matt.  So the pi appears okay.  I'm not familiar with retropi and do not know how much work would be required to get a GUI.  It might be trivial.  Perhaps someone else can enlighten us.

Comment: Matt is my son so thats a good sign! lol

Comment: @joan retropi just sits on top of Raspbian. Actually it's logged in as user pi and hostname is matt. Seems to be working fine apart from a dead link to retropi somewhere

Comment: @Dirk  which is the problem. My son unistalled retropi as he didn't want it, thinking it would just boot up normally as Rasbian.

Comment: It is booting normally to the command line. If you don't need to keep anything on the card I would write a fresh Raspbian Desktop image to the card using Etcher. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/

Comment: Success! I did end up rewriting the sd card. I was trying to follow a youtube video but Etcher was super easy. We have a happy young boy. thank you both for your assistance @dirk

Comment: @user90066 Good to hear that. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

It is booting normally to the command line. If you don't need to keep anything on the card I would write a fresh Raspbian Desktop image to the card using Etcher. See http://raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images